# Pegando vários valores de inputs iguais e armazendo num array com Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tenho essa div, que é `<div class='pergunta'>`, dentro dela tenho `<input type='text'> <select></select> <input type='checkbox'>` A questão é que essa div inteira pode se repetir caso eu clique em adicionar nova pergunta, ou seja, eu posso tem 1 ou N divs que contenham esses mesmos campos, eu preciso fazer um script em Javascript/jQuery que pegar o valor de cada campo e armazene em um array, por exemplo, eu tenho duas `<div class'pergunta'>` com esses campos, preciso adicionar os valores de cada campo em um array por exemplo:

```
var array = [{titulo: , tipo: , requerido: }, {titulo: , tipo: , requerido: }]
```

Ou seja, como faço pra adicionar os valores desses campos de cada div em um array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cria um seletor que apanhe todas as `<div class='pergunta'>` e depois faz um mapeamento para ir buscar os valores do titulo e tipo.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```js
const arr = $('.pergunta').map(function() {
  return {
    titulo: this.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value,
    tipo: this.querySelector('select').value,
    requerido: this.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').checked
  }
}).get();
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Funcionou !! O problema é que quando tento enviar esse 'arr' via ajax, método POST, ele está me retornando o seguinte erro: "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation".

Comment: @LeonardoTheodoro, usa `.get()` no final para transformar numa array nativa em vez de coleção jQuery.